# Exact same code - apk built in Android Studio is laggy and slow, same built in Eclipse fast and not laggy?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager, android-studio

So, I have run into a peculiar problem.

I have an Android app, originally developed in Eclipse, and then I migrated to Android Studio as I think its a much better IDE to work with.

So, I had some issues with a horizontal pager that was very slow, laggy and hard to use, and I thought there must be something wrong with the code. However, if another dev builds the same project/code (XML-files, java-files and SDK/references), the pager is not laggy at all - all the problems with the pager goes away completely.

The only difference is that the same code is built in Eclipse instead of Android Studio.

I find that basic behaviour is changed too:

- When I build the app in Android Studio, the horizontal pager works like this:
  If I start the drag movement, and I "catch the drag", any movement in vertical direction will immediately release/drop the "drag state". This makes it very hard to move the page in any direction, because you rarely move your finger EXACTLY horizontal.
- If the same thing is built with Eclipse, it works like this: 
  When the "drag" is in effect, it doesn't matter if I move my finger vertical, that movement is ignored. It is "locked in" to the drag effect, and thus makes it a lot easier to switch page. This is the behavious I want of course.

The pager used is like:

```
CirclePageIndicator extends View implements PageIndicator
```

and code for that one can be found [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java).

I have tried to figure out if there is a difference in SDK or target platform or something, but I can't find any relevant differences in build paths, SDKs, target platforms etc.

So, this is some images from Eclipse/dev setup:
[image]

And this is from my Android Studio computer:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: Have you made sure that all the support libraries are the same in both build systems? Also is there's a difference in size for the 2 APKs?

Comment: To add to what @Kai said, I would specifically check the android support library because it had a lot of changes/improvments between versions (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: Kai and Sean: THANKS! That helped! @kai - add it as a real answer, and Ill "award it" =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that all the support libraries are the same in both build systems, you can also check to see if there's a difference in size for the 2 APKs.
As @Sean pointed out, the difference in Android Support Library is probably the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with a canvas after migrating from Eclipse:

Refreshing a canvas in the APK generated with Eclipse worked at speed of light, but after migrating to Android Studio and with the same exact code the APK was very slow refreshing the canvas.

The solution i found:
In Android Studio, when starting the import process this dialog appears:

[Dialog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hlA8.png)

In order to avoid changing the libraries and making the app slow, it is only necessary to uncheck the checkboxes 'replace dependencies' and 'replace librery sources'

Also do not enable (or disable) instant run

That worked for me and the app canvas is now fast in Android Studio too